# Objective-C How do I enumerate a dictionary with letters and positions

Tags: objective-c, fast-enumeration

I think i blew up my brain. I have a dictionary with two arrays: letters and numbers. Numbers are the letters' positions on a board.

How can I enumerate over these arrays so that:

on a board of 64 squares, letter goes on its board number, and other board numbers are set to blank?

My goal is to allow people to select a square with a letter, and not crash if they select a square with no letter.

Comment: So what is the dictionary for?

Comment: I forgot to say that I will want a different item (shape, color, sound) at each loaded square. I thought a dictionary could be one way to identify what values at a specific position.

Comment: So you want a 64-entry array of dictionaries.  What specifically is your problem?

Comment: I can identify each square now, but I cannot seem to show the title nor other attributes. Using this: [button setTitle:@"a" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; I log the square and see that the value is correct.

Comment: oh, and I'm using tags instead of dictionaries right now

Comment: That sounds like a UI issue -- has nothing to do with arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: grrh. forgot to add the button as a subview.

Answer (score 3):

If I may suggest an alternative data structure, you might be better off with an array with a length of 64, each element representing a single square on the board. An empty string would represent an empty square, and a letter would represent a square with that letter.

For example:

```
// initialize game board
NSMutableArray *board = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int loop=0; loop<64; loop++) {
    [board addObject:@""]; // indicates an empty square
}

// set the pieces
board[17] = @"a";
board[23] = @"b";
board[61] = @"c";

// test a board square
if ([board[43] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    // square is empty
} else {
    // square has a letter
}
```

Comment: What if I need a different item (color, shape, sound) at each square?

Comment: Then, rather than an array of strings, you should create an array of `Square` objects. Create a `Square` class that has properties for what you need. If you need more help with that, probably ask a new question rather than using comments on this answer.

Comment: Yeah, the Square object is an alternative to using a dictionary.  The dictionary is simpler, in a way, since you can easily add a new attribute, but it's not a neat and "structured".  (I'd prefer using a dictionary in this case, but you haven't seen my office.)